# Why does Ubuntu still use a blacklisted graphics card claimed by stub?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, kvm-virtualization, blacklist

I am following [Multiheaded NVIDIA Gaming using Ubuntu 14.04 + KVM](http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/) tutorial and it seems like everything went well except that my ubuntu installation still shows HD7970 under Additional Drivers which should not happen as the device stubs are claimed as per the tutorial.

```
dom@SERVER:/usr/local/sbin$ dmesg | grep pci-stub
[    1.073038] pci-stub: add 1002:6798 sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF cls=00000000/00000000
[    1.073058] pci-stub 0000:01:00.0: claimed by stub
[    1.073068] pci-stub: add 1002:AAA0 sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF cls=00000000/00000000
[    1.073075] pci-stub 0000:01:00.1: claimed by stub
```

I am using Kaveri APU as primary GPU and Tahiti XT 7970 as virtual GPU. I have removed proprietary drivers. I am able to start booting into windows but it messes up my primary display with colors/patterns and also half the time freezes the system completely.

I would expect issues since the host OS still appears to see the discrete graphics. So my question is why does Ubuntu insist on using a blacklisted device/driver?